# HELP My wifi adapter is not working Unbuntu 20.04.2 lts

Tags: wireless, realtek-wireless

My intelbras dual band ac1200 adapter is being recognized by the system, but does not display the wifi networks.
I am a linux beginner and I have searched through several tutorials but I couldn't advance with any.

Output of `lsusb`:

[image: Output of lsusb]

Additional drivers:

[image: Additional Drivers tab]

Comment: What is the result from terminal for `mokutil --sb-state`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to fix this, while not ideal, is to use a custom driver for the RTL8812AU chipset that is in your wireless card.

Here's how:

0. Open Terminal
1. Ensure you have `git` and `dkms` installed on your machine:

   ```
   sudo apt install git dkms
   ```
2. Download the RTL8812AU driver:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git
   ```
3. Change to the directory:

   ```
   cd rtl8812au
   ```
4. Compile an install the driver:

   ```
   sudo make dkms_install
   ```

Once this is done, your wireless card should pick up properly. If not, you may need to reboot.